# How do I get fresh post data in post_publish hook?

Tags: plugins, taxonomy

I'm using the post_publish hook to do some operations in my plugin based on the post's taxonomies. If update a post, calling `get_the_category($id)` returns the categories for the post version *before* the update, not after it, which messes up the operations I'm running.

For example, if I publish a post with category id's 20 and 21, and try to get the post's categories in the post_publish hook, it works. If I then edit the post so it only has category 20, and try to the get categories in the post_publish hook, it returns categories 20 and 21, even though the update only has category 20. If I edit the post title, that is accurately reflected in the `$post` argument.

I have read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278986/get-updated-meta-data-after-save-post-hook) similar question, but that one concerns meta values, not taxonomies, and I'm not sure how to apply it's answer here.

How do I get the fresh taxonomy data? This also happens if I use the save_post hook.

```
add_action("publish_post", "process_published_post", 10, 2);

function process_published_post($id, $post) {
    $categories = get_the_category($id); 
    //Categories here are old when post is being updated
}
```

Comment: Have you checked `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` as your linked related question suggests in the answers?

Comment: Yes, but neither includes the post's taxonomies.

Comment: If I try this on a normal post, assign categories and print out the `$_POST` there's a key for `post_category` which has an array of assigned category IDs. Does this not happen with custom taxonomies?

Comment: I don't see that field. I am using one custom taxonomy, and this is a regular post type. This is the print_r of $_POST and $_REQUEST - https://imgur.com/a/ojAlczQ

Comment: Is it `tax_input`? Is your taxonomy slug `lift_theme`?

Comment: Yes, 'lift_theme', but that post has categories, tags, and a theme. Just the custom theme taxonomy appears.

Comment: Hmm... It looks like it should work out of the box. `publish_post` is run almost at the ent of `wp_insert_post` (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3851) and definitely after terms are set and caches are clean, so... Hmm

Comment: Hmm indeed. I'll try to dig into it more sometime later today or tomorrow and see if I find anything illuminating.

Comment: So I set up the hook to email me the post information with a timestamp when it runs, and it's weird. When I publish an update once, I get more than one email, though it doesn't seem consistent. I just got 4 emails from one update, two timestamped at 4:11:11PM, and those two had the old post data. Two more emails came in at 4:11:17PM, and they both had the fresh post data. Another time, same scenario, 1 email that was wrong, 5 seconds later, two that were correct. Thoughts? I'm not an avid wordpress developer, so it the problem could easily be in my plugin setup.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this please ?

Comment: I haven't touched this project in a while, but I don't believe I ever did. Ended up creating a process to generate the data fresh on each pull request instead of updating it on the post hook. Kind of a pain.